Inherit values from taxonomy custom field in the post that contain that taxonomy
I have a custom post type called "Jobs" and a custom taxonomy field called "Cities". Within the "Cities" taxonomy, there is a custom text field named "Zip Codes" where I input the zip codes within a certain radius of that city. I'm looking for a solution that will allow me to import these zip codes into the post based on the selected taxonomy. I am using WordPress, ACF, and Elementor.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
